# How to determine kubernetes version from within EKS node

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

We’re providing our own AMI node images for EKS using [the self-managed node feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/worker.html).
The challenge I’m currently having is how to fetch the kubernetes version from within the EKS node as it starts up.

I’ve tried IMDS - which unfortunately doesn’t seem to have it:

```
root@ip-10-5-158-249:/# curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
ami-id
ami-launch-index
ami-manifest-path
autoscaling/
block-device-mapping/
events/
hostname
iam/
identity-credentials/
instance-action
instance-id
instance-life-cycle
instance-type
local-hostname
local-ipv4
mac
metrics/
network/
placement/
profile
reservation-id
```

It also doesn’t seem to be passed in by the [EKS bootstrap script](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/blob/master/files/bootstrap.sh) - seems AWS is baking a single K8s version into each AMI. ([install-worker.sh](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/blob/master/scripts/install-worker.sh#L215)).

This is different from [Azure’s behaviour of baking a bunch of Kubelets into a single VHD](https://github.com/Azure/AgentBaker/blob/master/vhdbuilder/packer/install-dependencies.sh#L485).
I’m hoping for something like IMDS or a passed in user-data param which can be used at runtime to symlink kubelet to the correct kubelet version binary.

Comment: you can filter the EKS Kuberentes AMI by name in the AWS Console tho...

Comment: owner `602401143452` and AMI name : `amazon-eks-{{os_arch}}-node-{{k8s_version}}-v*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumed you build your AMI base on the EKS optimized AMI; one of the possible way is use `kubelet --version` to capture the K8s version in your custom built; as you knew EKS AMI is coupled with the control plane version. If you are not using EKS AMI, you will need to make `aws eks describe-cluster` call to get cluster information in order to join the cluster; which the version is provided at `cluster.version`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is a good suggestion.

The problem I'm trying to solve is a little different I think:
1. I'm providing an image with many versions of the kubelet binary installed (say kubelet-v1.22.0, kubelet-1.23.4, etc). This could be either based off of the EKS image and added onto or not.
2. Before starting the kubelet, I'd like to select which of the many kubelet binaries to run. 

How can I know which kubernetes version is running on the master node so I know to start a kubelet which is compatible?

Comment: Checkout the updated answer.

Comment: Yeah the `aws eks describe-cluster` is good assuming you know the cluster name and region which you can pass in via user-data. Answer accepted, thanks!